# Calcular sucesores de un nodo en grafo dirigido

Tags: c++, matrices

Dado el siguiente ejercicio:

> Considérese   la  clase   graph_t,
>   que   representa  un  grafo   dirigido    mediante    una matriz  de  incidencia, en  la  que la  posición    (i,j)   en  la  matriz  M_  representa  el  valor   del arco    que va  del vértice i-1     al  j-1 en  el  grafo.
>
> Si  este    valor
>   fuera  0   indicaría   que     dicho   arco    no  pertenece   al  grafo.  Por
>   otro   lado,  el   vector  de  listas  L_  representa  la  lista   de 
>   sucesores para    cada    nodo.   Es  decir,  el  elemento    i   del vector  contiene    la  lista   con los vértices    sucesores   de  i.
>
> Impleméntese  el  método  int delta_minus(int j)  const   que devuelve    el  número  de  predecesores    que tiene   el  vértice j   a   partir  de  la  matriz  M_.

Tengo la clase graph_t implementada:

```
class graph_t{
        private:
        matrix_t<int> M_;
        vector_t<dll_t<int> > L_;
        public:
        graph_t(void);
        ~graph_t(void);
        int get_n(void) const;
        int get_m(void) const;
        private:
        bool is_zero(int i, int j) const;
        private:
        void make_adjacence_list(void);
        };
```

y esta otra clase `matrix_t`:

```
template <class T>
class matrix_t
{
private:
 int m_;
 int n_;

 T* v_;

public:
 matrix_t(void);
 matrix_t(int m, int n);
 ~matrix_t(void);

 void resize(int m, int n);

 T& get_set (int i, int j);
 T get (int i, int j) const;

 int get_m(void) const;
 int get_n(void) const;
};
```

Encontré este ejercicio resuelto de la siguiente manera:

```
int graph_t :: delta_minus(int j){

int n_pred=0;

     for (int i=0; i<M_.get_m(); i++){

         if(!is_zero())
             n_pred++;
      }
}
```

Me imaginé el funcionamiento, `j` representa un nodo determinado pero en nuestra matriz es una columna determinada, entonces utilizamos un `for` para recorrer los distintos nodos `i` y hacer la comprobación con `is_zero()`.

Si dicha comparación devuelve que hay distancia es que `j` es predecesor de los nodos `i`

¿estoy en lo cierto?

¿exactamente el mismo código nos calcularía los sucesores de `j`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por ahi va la idea 
corriges esta linea `if(!is_zero())` te comento en el codigo la respuesta:

```
int graph_t :: delta_minus(int j){

int n_pred=0;

     for (int i=0; i<M_.get_m(); i++){
         /*
         La posición (i,j) en la matriz M_ representa el valor del 
         arco que va del vértice i-1 al j-1 en el grafo.
         (segun el ejercicio) 
          entonces el predecesor es i para el arco (i,j)
         Nota que si te piden j el nodo esta en la posicion j-1

         */
         if(!is_zero())
          //is_zero() sin parametros no esta implementado 
          //debe ser is_zero(i,j-1) para contar los predecesores
          //debe ser is_zero(j-1,i) para contar los sucesores
             n_pred++;
      }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda te puedo hacer una pregunta sobre listas? gracias

Comment: muchas gracias de verdad